# How to use get() multiple times in c++ 11 future or how to get a vector values?

Tags: c++, c++11, asynchronous, vector, future

I have a function what is return with a vector

```
    std::vector<int> makecode(std::vector<std::string> row)
```

and my program:

```
    std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> data(n);
    std::vector<std::future<std::vector<int>>> results(n);
    for(size_t i =0;i<n;++i){
         results.push_back(std::async(std::launch::async,makecode, data[i]));
    }
    for(std::future<std::vector<int>>& f : results){
         f.wait();
         f.get();;
    }
```

I get this exception:

> ```
> what(): No associated state Error...
> ```

Yes I can't use get multiple times so I use `results.push_back(std::move(f));` line and if I not comment `f.wait()` line the result is the same error.

Everything working except this.  How can I get the vectors what made by my "makecode" function?

Comment: I think with `std::shared_future`. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/shared_future

Comment: You initialized your vector of futures with `n` empty ones, and pushed more onto the back

Comment: `std::vector<...> results(n);` creates a `vector` with `n` elements. You aren't doing anything with them (you're just adding more) so the `future`s there aren't associated with anything.

Comment: [This works](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/eb9fed1959a13695), and hence I'm voting to close as typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create your `vector` you initialize it with `n` elements. These futures aren't associated with anything so when you try to `wait` on them they throw an exception. To fix, change:

```
std::vector<std::future<std::vector<int>>> results(n);
```

to

```
std::vector<std::future<std::vector<int>>> results;
```

Or alternatively assign to each element instead of calling `push_back`:

```
std::vector<std::future<std::vector<int>>> results(n);
for(size_t i =0;i<n;++i){
     results[i] = std::async(std::launch::async,makecode, data[i]);
}
```